# how to change the MTU size permanently in EC2 Ubuntu18.04 instance?

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to change the `MTU` size of `Ubuntu 18.04 EC2` instance back to `1500` from `9000` since my other cloud instance's `MTU` set to `1500`. I tried various solutions like adding below two lines in the `/etc/dhcp/dhcpclient.conf` file before the `request` line.

`default interface-mtu 1500;`
`supersede interface-mtu 1500;`

But it didn't work. I want to change the `MTU` size permanently. I also tried the solution like changing the `MTU` using command `sudo ifconfig eth0 mtu 1500` but these are temporary.

Also, the `/etc/network/interfaces` is empty as they are using `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` file instead. I tried to add the `MTU` size in `50-cloud-init.yaml` file too but It didn't work either.

output `netstat -i` command

```
netstat -i
Kernel Interface table
Iface      MTU    RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg
docker0   1500        0      0      0 0             0      0      0      0 BMU
eth0      9001     4836      0      0 0          4930      0      0      0 BMRU
lo       65536      132      0      0 0           132      0      0      0 LRU
```

Please help.

Comment: "how to change the MTU size permanently in EC2 Ubuntu18.04 instance?" is not what the body asks; chanign the MTU -other- than 1500 or -on specific instances!- to 9001 is not possible. You are asking about how to reset it back to 1500. The official docs says `sudo ip link set dev eth0 mtu 1500` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/network_mtu.html and 2 other methods for Amazon Linux and Amazon Linux 2.

Comment: @Rinzwind 
I already went through the Amazon docs and they have mentioned this `For other Linux distributions, consult their specific documentation`.  Also, I have mentioned the word `permanently` and the command that u have shared is a `temporary` solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the subject of a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1807273 It was closed as Fixed by the changes to netplan.io in version 0.96. I assume that you already have version 0.96 or later; confirm:

```
sudo dpkg -s netplan.io
```

Comment #25 in the bug report suggests the netplan entries to effect the change. I suggest:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp4-overrides:
        use-mtu: false
      mtu: 1500
      match:
        macaddress: 99:12:92:f8:f9:99
      set-name: eth0
```

Of course, substitute the actual MAC addrss here. Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Confirm:

```
ip addr show
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I would like to add that only 2 settings in netplan configuration are important here, i.e. `match` with `macaddress` and `mtu` value